# How to call an event when the user "finally" selects an item in a list?

Tags: user-interface, language-agnostic, events, terminology, selected

When a user clicks once on an item in a Grid or a ListBox, that item is usually *selected*, hence most UI frameworks have a `onSelected` event or the like for that.

However, how can we generally call the next step when a user "finally" selects an item by e.g. double clicking an entry? You know when some popup might appear in the context of the selected item and the user can do further stuff.

Strangely enough, I think I have never seen a word for that in any UI framework.

`onPicked`, `onAccepted`, `onChosen`, `onFinallySelected`, `onResult`? All kinda awkward or too special. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found anything wrong with [SelectionChangeCommitted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: In this case it seems it means that the selection was not done programmatically, but by user interaction instead. However, something with `Committed` might be a solution indeed.

Comment: Yeah, I like "Committed" too.  Definitely gives the impression of "this is my final answer!"  8 D

Answer (score 1):

The `wxWidgets` framework uses the term `activated` to describe what you're talking about. So, the method could be called `onActivated`.